Memory management BSOD after installing new ssd
I've been using my laptop for a while now with no issues and a one terabyte HDD. Last week I replaced the HDD with a one terabyte SSD and installed windows 11 onto it.
In the week since the purchase, I've had to clean install windows 4 times because it keeps crashing and getting corrupted with a memory management blue screen of death. I've never had this BSOD until I installed the SSD but research suggests it's a memory issue?
I only have one 8gb ddr4 stick that has been working fine for years. Is this a problem with my SSD most likely? Can I fix this my getting a new ssd?

You should test both, RAM and SSD.

Hi @ChanganAuto quick checks on both seem to suggest both are fine. Memory management and disk checking utilities

Probably also worth mentioning I frequently boot Ubuntu from an external HDD(the former HDD) now with no problems at all


Was the PC originally running Win 11, or were two changes made, i.e., installing Win 11 and replacing the HDD with SSD. 2. Since the HDD still works, it is not a memory issue. Are you sure the SSD is compatible with the PC??


Yes @DrMoishePippik, the pc was running win 11 prior to installing the hdd and never got a blue screen for about the 1+ years the HDD was installed. The SSD is a sata disk by WD blue

Try imaging the old drive to the SSD and see if you experience the same behavior.

Practically formatted the old drive already @Blindspots. Replaces the SSD though and it still happens. Ran a 6 hour test using memtest86+ and got 6 passes and 0 fails. Installed ubuntu on the ssd and it works fine now. Honestly sick of windows.
